# Android Ad Size Issue

Tags: android, eclipse, admob, google-play-services

so in my LogCat, I received the following error which I'm assuming is why my ad would not show up when I used my phone to test it.  How come the size is not working even though I set the banner ad to "SMART_BANNER"?  Shouldn't it auto adjust the size?

Code & LogCat:

[image: LogCat]

[image: Java code]

[image: XML]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are using Left and Right Padding... It is narrowing the available space and for the adView you need more space... Remove the paddings and it will work